# django mathfilters in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-views

How to compute the final average of every students in views.py and post it in html template?

for example I have two(2) students, I will get the average of every Grading Categories(Exam, Quizzes, Homework, Classwork) to get the final rating

[image]

first is I need to compute it in views.py and post it in my html template, I don't know how to do it so please me guys

this is my models.py

```
Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null=True, blank=True)
Grading_Categories = models.ForeignKey(gradingCategories, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       null=True, blank=True)
Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrolledSubject, related_name='+',
                                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
Average = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

when I tried this

YourModel.objects.values('Grading_Categories').annotate(avg= Avg('Average'))

[image]

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
YourModel.objects.values('Grading_Categories').annotate(avg= Avg('Average'))
```